# Expo client run in phone communication with local backend

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, expo

I'm trying out the communication between my backend / frontend. The application is developed in react native and my backend is based on spring boot. When I run my application in my phone through the Expo Go app I can't send http requests to my backend (it works with postman at: localhost:8080/user).

When I try to do the same requests in my application I have defined the following function:

```
export function signup(signupRequest) {
  return fetch({
    url: "192.168.10.152:8080" + "/user",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(signupRequest)
  });
}
```

And then I get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
```

If it helps I run my backend on ubuntu 20.04 and I got my local ip with the command

> ip a

Update, I have no updated my application.properties in my spring-boot project like this:

```
server.address=192.168.10.152
server.port=8080
```

I still get the same error when I try to make a post-request from my react native application however.

Comment: If your backend runs on localhost:8080: change the ip adresse to <your-ip-adress>:8080

Comment: Where should I change that? In my react native code I have already declared it..

Comment: In your backend, the two ip adresses must match

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: Try to add http:// to url in your post request

Comment: Nope, did not work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243964/discussion-between-j-dev-and-qer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to push my backend to the domain with https protocol and everything was ok. There's an application, [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that allows you to send requests to a server but using other link with https protocol.

For example, if you have your backend server on localhost:5000, then you need to open ngrok command line and integrate your server with `ngrok http 5000` command. As the result you'll get a link that will look like this:

> https://f971-31-128-76-233.eu.ngrok.io